# UITextView renders custom font incorrectly in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitextview, multilingual, right-to-left, custom-font

My app uses a UITextView to input Syriac text (Estrangelo font), but UITextView renders some letters incorrectly like this:

[image]

I tested it with a UILabel and a UITextView. UILabel displays it correctly, but UITextView incorrectly displays the top dots and moves them to the bottom (see the above result).

This problem only occurs in iOS 7 and does not occur in iOS 6. Please tell me if there's any way to fix the problem.

This is [my test code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/55xqzlkks2sjy1x/TestListFont.zip)

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-40);
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"East Syriac Adiabene" size:24];
label.text = @"ܩ̈ ܡ̄ ܬ̇ ܒ̃";
[self.view addSubview:label];

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
textView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y+40);
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"East Syriac Adiabene" size:24];
textView.text = @"ܩ̈ ܡ̄ ܬ̇ ܒ̃";
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: up voted so you get some of your bounty back and yikes, glad that problem isn't mine!

Comment: I can say with certainty, that Apple has had issues with their font system, particularly their pixel measurements and placements.  After much research into the topic an personal work on MacOS and iOS, I have seen postings on apple's website to the effect they already know they have these issues.  I think they are working on it, but it is an architectural problem that will most likely not be fixed in a single version, but take multiple releases to pan out all of their issues.

Comment: Have you tried the 7.1 beta? No idea if it's actually fixed, just wondering.

Comment: it is so interesting.. i played with your code and use text field instead of text view, text field font looks correct before editing. it becomes exactly like text view after press on it...

Comment: Each symbol in your string consists of two symbols: main character and modifier letter ("tilda", "dot" or "double dot"), and iOS rendering engine mixes them up (may be confused by right-left text direction). I just tried to swap characters in each pair in your example and it started looking similar to UILabel, but far from needed result. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dh4pqp19g3lmivv/Screenshot%202014-02-09%2023.26.11.png

Comment: Thanks @VadimKalinsky Could you post question in detail. I use textView because my App is a keyboard, input text dynamically

Comment: @iMS It may be worth noting that when I pasted those characters into the url/search box in Chrome, I witnessed the same effect. I agree that it seems to be a confusion of RTL text in a LTR field. However, I experimented with setting `UITextView` to a writing direction of right-to-left, and it still renders incorrectly. This made me wonder if the string itself needs to have some RTL specifier, so I prepended the string with the [0x200F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) char, and still no luck.

Comment: I think it's the right moment to use your tech support from Apple if you never do, cause here it's a real big problem, good luck : https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#requestTechSupport

Comment: I'm trying to create a project to look at this issue, however the Estrangelo V1.1 font that I've found doesn't work at all. Where did you download it?

Comment: Thanks @tarmes, yes Estrangelo not work,I make a list of font. I don't check one by one. I change to "East Syriac Adiabene". The file name is SyrCOMAdiabene.otf in my code. The problem also exist.

Comment: if i try to delete hardcode text in from left to right it delete right to left and try right to left it's going left to left. why it is happen.

Comment: This language order from right to left like Arabic @iDev

Comment: so for it happens for delete the character from right side it going left to right postion. it is correct way

Comment: Yes, input and delete like Arabic. Problem in typing, from left to right and add above symbol. @iDev

Comment: this issue is only happen in ios 7 do you know this information

Comment: I would recommend you file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: What do you get using CoreText to draw the string?

Comment: I just input text from custom keyboard to UITextView and this problem happen, I'm not using Coretext @AbhiBeckert

Comment: @iMS yeah I know... but I suspect you will have to use CoreText to solve your problem. Unfortunately that that might require weeks of programming on your part. CoreText is a complicated API to work with.

Comment: @iMS - your attachment is not working .. :)

Comment: I've been reverse engineering this. It seems `UILabel` leaves layout to CoreText, while `UITextView`, using `NSLayoutManager`, does the layout itself incorrectly. This is the reason for the inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I debugged this issue a little, and it seems to be a bug in the way `NSLayoutManager` layouts the text. As other answers pointed out, `UITextView` is build around TextKit since iOS7, and thus uses `NSLayoutManager` internally to layout text. `UILabel` uses Core Text to layout text directly. Both eventually use Core Text to render the glyphs.

You should open a bug report with Apple and post the number so people can duplicate it. The issue has not been fixed so far in iOS7.1 betas.

As a workaround, you can replace `UITextView` with other Core Text alternative editors, which layout and render directly with Core Text, where the issue does not exist.

I tested [`SECoreTextView`](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SECoreTextView), and it shows the text correctly. It implements a similar API to `UITextView` but internally uses Core Text.

Here is how it looks after swapping `UITextView` with `SECoreTextView`:

```
SETextView *textView = [[SETextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
textView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y+40);
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:desc size:24];
textView.text = @"ܩ̈ ܡ̄ ܬ̇ ܒ̃";
textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.editable = YES;

[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

[image: Using Core Text, the layout issue does not exist.]

Comment: iOS7 API makes me unhappy

Comment: @VitalyS. Give it time to mature. TextKit is very new for Apple in iOS. Make sure to open a bug report so Apple can fix it eventually!

Answer (score 2):

Some days ago, I had the same problem as yours in `iOS 7` ***(but the font was different)***.
I set the **FONT** after setting the **TEXT** and it worked for me. So for your case:

```
textView.text = @"ܩ̈ ܡ̄ ܬ̇ ܒ̃"; // Setting the text.
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"East Syriac Adiabene" size:24]; // Setting the font and it's size.
```

It may seem silly, but it worked for me.

Also see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113673/uitextview-setting-font-not-working-with-ios-6-on-xcode-5). There are many tips for using custom fonts with `UITextView`, which may be helpful for you.

**EDIT :**

iOS 7 also introduced a new `selectable` property on the `UITextView` for enabling text selection. So make sure you have done the following:

```
self.textField.editable = YES;
self.textField.selectable = ON;
```

Comment: Sorry, not work with me both in simulator and device.

Comment: @iMS - can you attach here, your demo project source code with only label, textView and custom font ?? Thanks :)