# Change text parameters in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to display some text in a UITextView (no editable) and I am having some problems to change font size, color...

I am using xcode 5 with ios6 appearance. I tried to change parameters in nib file: arribute inspector> text view.

But all I try, seems to do nothing. Nothing changes, I see the text equal as if I didn't modify anything.

I don't write text inside uitextview, I just show it from a variable.

Comment: have you make IBOutlet connection for the textview

Comment: YEs. I see the text in the uitextview. I just don't see the text effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problems and had already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113673/uitextview-setting-font-not-working-with-ios-6-on-xcode-5/19168777#19168777)

You need to set the text of your `UITextView` and after you can set the font and the color :

```
_myTextView.text = @"text";
[_myTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:18.0f]];
_myTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: That is. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before. It got fixed when I did the customization after selecting the entire default text.

Here is a sample screenshot :

[image]

Hope this helps !

Comment: The problem is that I leave text in blank because I will set other text by code. Anyway, I solved it by setting properties after setting the text. I will post the answer when the page allows me.