# attributedText not setting with UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, custom-font

I am trying to set custom font.

Font is working with `UILabel`.

When I tries to use for `UITextView`, its not working. `UITextView` is taking default font.

Any idea how to use custom font for `UITextView`.

Code I am using is as below.

```
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
    attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"GEDinarOne-Medium" 
    size:15], NSLigatureAttributeName: @2}];
abtUsText.attributedText = attributedString;
abtUsText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
abtUsText.textColor = cb60756;
```

I am using `attributedString` to get working with `iOS 6`.

`iOS 7` is giving proper font, but `iOS 6` is using default font for `UITextView` only.

### Edit 1

### I am using arabic font as GEDinarOne-Medium

---

### Edit 2

This is not duplicate of what is mentioned above as my case is with arabic font and not english font. Mentioned in duplicate works with english custom fonts only.

Comment: Have you checked the objects and properties you are using is also available in IOS 6 ?

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString working for > iOS6

Comment: @iPatel : yes my app is iOS 6+ (iOS 6, iOS 7)

Comment: @iPatel : any idea how to get it working for UITextView (for iOS 6)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView - setting font not working with iOS 6 on XCode 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113673/uitextview-setting-font-not-working-with-ios-6-on-xcode-5)

Comment: @cweinberger : I tried all, its not working... especially I am using arabic font... (may be what you have works for english custom fonts and not arabic fonts).. for arabic I have to use attributedstring...

Comment: is it working with default system fonts?

Comment: @cweinberger : yes... all is fine with default fonts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I investigate custom font (***especially arabic***) is not working `UITextView` using `attributedString`, below is what I did.

I just wanted to display the text in `UITextView` (for About Us in my app) as it has long text and I wanted scrolling option.

Below is what I did.

1. Add `UIScrollView`
2. Add `UILabel` inside  `UIScrollView`
3. Assign text to `UILabel`.

   `abtUsLabel.attributedText = attributedString;`
4. Make label `sizeToFit`

   `[abtUsLabel sizeToFit];`

   This is very important step, else it won't work.
5. Set scrollview `contentSize` as per label height.

   `[abtUsScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(abtUsScrollView.frame.size.width, abtUsLabel.frame.size.height)];`

Done... now if the Label is longer, we can scroll it.

Comment: Glad that you've found a solution which is working for you. However, please keep in mind that UILabels are not perfect for long text. If you reach a certain length, the label won't be drawn completely / partially (as UILabel will render the complete text into the graphic buffer and there are limitations (graphic memory)).

Comment: actually chances of scrolling is less and even if scrolling is needed, max 2 times scrolling will be there

Comment: @FahimParkar hmm, you are right about custom fonts. I have the same problem with it. Do you have any document about custom fonts error with UITextView `attributedString`?

Comment: @user2335125 : [May be this solution will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19168661/1066828) Regarding document, I don't have.