# Text is not fully displayed in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, autolayout

My `UITextView` is being very weird.

To explain the problem, the `UITextView` is placed in an `UITableViewCell`, and at the first display, the second line is missing :

[image]

If I continue scrolling down, and go back to see this `UITextView`, everything is back to normal:

[image]

What is very weird, is that if I set my `UITextView` as none selectable (what I want in fact), the text is well displayed, but the font is lost :

[image]

It seems that I have the same problem described here:
[UITextView - setting font not working with iOS 6 on XCode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113673/uitextview-setting-font-not-working-with-ios-6-on-xcode-5)

and the fix given (setting the `UITextView` as Selectable) worked fine for the font. But this problem with the cropped text makes this solution inadequate.

The `UITextView` has a red background color to be sure that the size is ok.

Everything is done in a Storyboard, but I also tried to set the font manually, the problem is still there.

Have you any hint of what could be wrong?

Comment: I had a similar problem before, UITextView seems to have some bugs. What I did was to increase the height of the text view, made it larger than what was necessary, and the full text appeared. Check if that works for you.

Comment: It seems working, but it's not exactly what I want to do ^^
I have another solution, do `[cell.textview layoutIfNeeded]` but I'm afraid it kills my `UITableView` performance...

Comment: Could you please post the code you have within cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Also having serious problems with UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoLayout to adjust the UITextView size inside the cell or you can use

`[cell.textView sizeToFit];`

I recommend using AutoLayout as it shouldn't harm the performance so much.