# attributed text on UITextview in Storyboard nor working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a ViewController with an UITextView on it. I have several paragraphs in UITextView and am trying to give different fonts and colors on each paragraph. In the last paragraph, I made it center aligned and changed the color to red. Just the last paragraph.

Here is a change I made in storyboard:
[image]

And below image is what I see in storyboard. You can see the change is correctly being made.
[image]

However, when I run the app the changes I made (center aligned, red color) are applied to all paragraphs in the textview when I only made the changes on one paragrpah. Is there a way to make changes only on certain parts of the text in UITextView??

Comment: It would appear that attributed strings are just **totally broken**.  Whatever you do in storyboard, simply does not appear in the app.  it's a disaster.  The "selectable" workaround does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Xcode with me right now, but I feel it might have to do with a bug in Xcode where setting attributed text in IB either doesn't work or gives the wrong result. Try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113673/uitextview-setting-font-not-working-with-ios-6-on-xcode-5) (which sadly still apply to iOS 9/Xcode 7), or if that doesn't work, you may have to just do it programatically (using `NSAttributedString` to set the text on the text view).