# How to make marquee UILabel / UITextField / NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, nstextfield, marquee

I need to make marquee `UILabel` in Xcode. The marquee will scroll from right to left.

I tried  `CCScrollingLabel` also `JHTickerView` and others. But i can not find simple code with marquee with out any views/arrays/some stupid libraries and others

How to make marquee with `UILabel`? (`UITextField` and `NSTextField` are OK too).

Comment: Have a look at this, May be this is helpfull.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232801/itunes-song-title-scrolling-in-cocoa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `NSTimer` and you need to invoke a method something as :

**This is for OSX, you can easily convert it into iOS, `NSTextField` and `UILabel` has different methods.*

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    self.myTimer=[NSTimer new];
    self.fullString=@"This is a long string to be shown.";
    [self.label setAlignment:NSRightTextAlignment];
}


-(void)scrollText:(id)parameter{
    static NSInteger len;
    [self.label setStringValue:[self.fullString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, len++)]];

    if (self.label.stringValue.length==self.fullString.length) {
        [self.myTimer invalidate];
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2f
                                                    target: self
                                                  selector:@selector(scrollText:)
                                                  userInfo: nil 
                                                   repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Anoop: If the length of NSTextField is less than the length of NSString, its not displaying the full string. How to display full string.

Comment: @ArunPratap: In that case, you need to truncate tail, and then add some logic to append text...