# IOS Autoscroll Label scrolling from right to left

Tags: ios, marquee

I am using the library `AutoScrollLabel` for `autoScrollLabel` like marquee and its working perfect when I need the `label` to scroll from left to right.

But when I have to use the direction from right to left I have facing this problem:

the label begin from the last word to the first?

Why?

You can find below my code:

```
self.autoScrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.autoScrollLabel.labelSpacing = 1; // distance between start and end labels
self.autoScrollLabel.pauseInterval = 0; 
self.autoScrollLabel.scrollSpeed = 70; // pixels per second
self.autoScrollLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; 
self.autoScrollLabel.fadeLength = 0; 
self.autoScrollLabel.scrollDirection = CBAutoScrollDirectionRight;
self.autoScrollLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"",@"hello hello1 hello1 heeloo3 hello3 hebe hehehe hgdghdhg he e e hehee hehee hehehehehehhe"];
```

Comment: check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397122/how-to-move-text-from-right-to-left-in-ios-programatically

Comment: @KiritModi thank you but this is not what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `AutoScrollLabel` class, but I think in order to it worked properly you should change property

```
self.autoScrollLabel.scrollDirection = CBAutoScrollDirectionLeft
```

when you scroll to the left

Answer (score 0):

for Swift you you can call this method :

```
 func startMarqueeLabelAnimation() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 20.0, delay: 1, options: ([.curveLinear, .repeat]), animations: {() -> Void in
            self.marqueeLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.marqueeLabel.bounds.size.width / 2, y: self.marqueeLabel.center.y)

        }, completion:  nil)

    })
}
```

Comment: This is shifting of whole label, not scrolling. Can cause issue when app goes in background and comes in foreground, your label will be disappears.